# How do I open the Windows Task Manager during a Remote Desktop session?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, task-manager, ctrl-alt-delete

When I press Ctrl-Alt-Delete I can only open the Task Manager for the local PC.

Is there some simple way to open the Task Manager on the remote PC while running Remote Desktop from one Windows XP machine to another?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Right-click the taskbar and click Task Manager.
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> will serve the purpose if its not allowing to click anywhere.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know XP had that.

Comment: I can't tell you how many times I use that in a day!  :-)

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + Escape works too, I think Ctrl + Alt + Delete gives you back control over your own computer doesn't it?

Comment: How about in an RDP connection to a Mac PC?

Comment: In my case (Windows 7 local, Windows Server 2012 remote), Ctrl+Shift+Esc was handled by the local system and not the remote one.  [pelms' answer](http://superuser.com/a/9610/319773) however, Ctrl+Alt+End, worked just fine.

Answer (score 64):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>, then press <kbd>t</kbd>

Comment: ??? on what platform is that? Doesn't work on my XP...

Comment: Opps, Ctrl+Alt+End brings up the 'Window Security' dialog, added 't' for the Task Manager button.

Comment: +1 In my case, the remote machine was running a program which prohibited use of the taskbar and start menu. I was able to use this to kill that process.

Comment: Nice trick to use after click "Exit Explorer".

Comment: This one just saved my bacon.  Explorer was shut down from an installation, and restarting explorer.exe wasn't working.  I was able to remotely log out and log back in to get the shell back.

Comment: works, but really I don't have enough fingers to push all the needed keys for that:)

Answer (score 28):

Or click Start → Run, then type `taskmgr`.

Comment: I will have to remember. I incorrectly tried taskman... taskmgr taskmgr taskmgr :)

Answer (score 8):

If Jonas may have been meaning he had a *windowed* remote desktop session, and he wondered what keyboard shortcut would open Task Manager on that remote, there is a shortcut for that (not mentioned yet in other answers here):

<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>home</kbd>

Since he mentioned using <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>del</kbd>, it seems most focused on showing how to do THAT against in the remote (windowed or not), or how to open task manager other ways in the remote. Those are not wrong answers, but if Jonas (or other readers finding this post) wondered if there was such a keyboard shortcut for a windowed RDP session, hope this helps.

I have a blog post with still more such shortcuts for a "windowed" remote desktop: [Helpful keyboard shortcuts for working with "windowed" Remote Desktop: switching windows, more](http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2013/2/6/remote_desktop_keyboard_shortcuts)

Answer (score 3):

You can set the Windows key combinations to go to the remote computer and use Ctrl-Shift-Esc to launch the Task Manager.

In the remote desktop connection options for Local Resources you have the option of where to apply Windows key combinations (On the local computer, On the remote computer, or only in full screen mode).

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Esc works for me like that by default...

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Esc will work in full screen but if running in a window it will open the client PC's task manager

Answer (score 1):

If you just needed to enumerate processes on remote PC, you do not need to establish RDP session.

Take a look at Remote Process Manager http://admintoyssuite.com/l/remote-task-manager--view-and-kill-processes-and-applications-on-network-desktop-computers/

I found this way more flexible than to disturb currently logged on user with RDP connection prompt. Remote Process Manager connects on-the-fly and do not show any question boxes to remote users..

Comment: David, could you please disclose your affiliation with the product according to the [FAQ]? Excessive self-promoting is not welcome here.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> will work on Remote Desktop.

Comment: I had a solid white screen but was successfully connected via RDP. This answer made my normal desktop appear. Kudos.

Note: further testing reveals that Ctrl+Alt+Esc acts basically like a remote Alt+F4 (close window).

Comment: This does not work if you have a remote desktop inside a remote desktop. It only launches the task manager of the 1st remote.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> doesn't work in windowed (non-full screen) mode. Host Task Manager will be invoked.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> doesn't work in nested RDP session. Menu for outer RDP session will be displayed.

If you need to start Task Manager to rescue your server in nested session / windowed mode - **just switch to full screen mode temporary** with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> where you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>. This key combination will be send to the most nested RDP session in full screen mode.

Other cool tips: https://blog.codinghorror.com/remote-desktop-tips-and-tricks/

Answer (score 0):

In **nested** remote desktop sessions the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> brings up the taskmanager of the 1st remote Windows.

To invoke the taskmanager of the 2nd remote Windows I use the *On-Screen Keyboard* of the 1st remote Windows.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd>.

The details are on my blog: [How to Open the Task Manager on Remote Computer or Desktop](http://ckarthik17.blogspot.co.at/2010/01/how-to-open-task-manager-on-remote.html)